# PopOverWindow over a normal UIButton Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I am looking for a Methode to use the PopOverWindow with a normal Button.
I found informationen about the Storyboard in combination with the button PopOverView but I dont use a Story board.
So i Need help or a tutorial, of it.
Thanks soo much.

Comment: PopOverView is available for iPad only. It is available even without storyboards. You dont have to use storyboards for this specific feature. It is available using xibs too

Comment: Yes I wat to use on a iPad but How can I use it do you have some stuff for read (tutorials, or something else) for Buttons not for a BarButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```

and pass it the frame of your button as the first argument.

Comment: AWESOME!!! i tried it but not with the knowledge that I have to use the frame of my button :D thank you soooo much

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)yourButton:(UIButton*)sender
{
    VC1 *vcObject =  [[VC1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"VC1" bundle:nil];
    _popOver= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vcObject];
    _popOver.delegate = self;
    _popOver.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(330, 362); // set the size of the popOver you want in your app
    [_popOver presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; //sender.frame is the button's frame here
}
```

note: _popOver is an ivar mentioned in the particular VC

Comment: Also note to check the view where you want to show your popover view.